# This question asking what a functional version of a code would look like has been put on hold and I don't see why

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57614432/1244884) has been put on hold and I don't understand the reasons that motivated the decision.

The input and output have been well defined and the OP isn't asking broad questions such as "What is functional programming?".

The question looks clear and reasonably scoped to me. OP knows how to process the data, they're simply asking what a functional version of a data processing pipeline  would look like.

I voted to reopen this question. Was I wrong?

Comment: No research is shown, no attempt at processing the data appears to have been made.
SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: But that's not news... Look at the highest voted comments on there.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO where the highest voted answer isn't necessarily the best answer. I would be cautious before using a vote count as a measure of quality or good judgment in this particular situation.

Comment: Yea, but 8 upvotes on a comment that's not even a day old can't be ignored.

Comment: Trying to encourage people to ask more questions like this is only going to do one thing: make them hit the question ban that much faster.  I'd rather have them ask a proper question, so they can contribute properly, and, y'know, keep asking.  Or we can keep feeding them into the ban, too, I guess.  Either one maintains quality, but only one satisfies both askers and curators.

Comment: It certainly cannot you're right. But you must also taken into account that people also make bad judgments because they didn't read everything. Hence why there are tests in the reviewing queues.

Comment: @customcommander: Sure, people _"make bad judgements"_. but that doesn't make the question not  "too broad", or not a duplicate... That also doesn't make the comment or the votes on it "wrong".

Comment: I think we can all agree to respectfully disagree on this. I believe there was a reason to be flexible in this particular case. I came to ask for clarification and had a satisfactory answer. Thank you all for your inputs; they make sense and I'll certainly take them into consideration next time.

Answer (score -40, accepted):

It's a good question, and it's on-topic.

Contrary to [Cerbrus's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388795/this-question-asking-what-a-functional-version-of-a-code-would-look-like-has-bee/388799#comment723712_388795)

> No research is shown, no attempt at processing the data appears to have been made. SO is not a code writing service.
>
> [image]

[Lack of Research has never been a reason to close a question on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88521/16587) (it is, however, a reason to downvote the question).

I've re-opened the question and will keep an eye on it.

A duplicate was posted in the comments; I've since closed the question as a duplicate and the source duplicate will solve the OP's issue.

Comment: George, that comment contained 2 links, both are required to solve the 2 separate problems described in the questions.

Comment: If that question was a duplicate, closing it as such is the right thing to do. Thanks for your clarification. Your answer may not be the most popular but it certainly looks fair to me. Thank you.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not when you first posted it. See my screenshot above.

Comment: _"A duplicate was posted in the comments"_ That's the comment I was talking about. That comment contained ___2___ links. Why would you think I was talking about my comment on this meta question?

Comment: @Cerbrus because you said "that comment" and I only referenced your meta comment in my post. I don't know *who* left the main question comment because it gets deleted when the post gets closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can't moderators view deleted comments?

Comment: "It's a good question" No! We get hundreds of these questions of that kind. I once answered these  type of questions and often I ended up either explaining all the js fundamentals or applying more requirements than originally specified by the OP. We have to require a *minimum effort* here, to make sure that the OP will be able to adapt and work with the answers, and that the answers are at all helpful. From the answers given you can see that the only consequence of reopening were a few *really bad answers that help no one at the end*. I agree with the dupevote though.

Comment: @jonaswilms it is a good question — because just like the duplicates before it, it asks how to do something with new language, so next time we will have even more language to use to figure out if the question is a duplicate. People say the same things 1000 different ways, and without these questions to hone the language people use into something that we can easily identify as a duplicate, it’s hard for us to be immediately and persistently useful. Embrace duplicates; they make the routing system even better.

Comment: @georgeStocker hmm, maybe I finally take the time to write a good canonical for "how to turn datastructure x into Y using map/filter/reduce in JS?"

Comment: What are you linking to? Where in the linked post is it made clear that "lack of research has never been a reason to close a question on Stack Overflow"? I and others have closed questions for that reason for years without a problem. What has changed? Am I missing something? I am pretty confused.

Comment: @modus did you read the question and the answer?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yes. It has nothing to do with the requirement to do basic research and trying something by yourself.

Comment: @modus If we can’t agree on the premise of the question that is mentioned in the question itself we can’t really have a productive conversation past that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yeah, sorry, I am a patient person, but whatever. I know it's not your fault, but can Stack Overflow _please_ get their act together and state clearly what questions are supposed to be, and can elected moderators _please_ wait until this process is finished _before_ starting to moderate on new grounds? I am fed up with this. Stating that it has never been a reason to close a question is plain wrong.

Comment: @modus I linked you to a question from 2011 where this was true; I’ve linked to answers I’ve given to questions from 2008 and 2009 where this was true, and it’s been in every meta stack overflow/exchange answer I’ve given since before and after I was elected in 2013 on this subject. This is not new and it’s something we’ve had to fight off since I joined Stack Overflow in 2008. There’s always been a contingent that wants to close questions due to a lack of research effort and they’ve always been wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1288408

Comment: @GeorgeStocker And please don't tell me it's locked because new guidelines are being discussed because that is _exactly_ what I mean: wait for that process to be finished, then start to moderate based on new guidelines.

Comment: @modus we don’t have a close reason (on purpose) for lack of research effort. Part of the community wants it; but we even took “minimal understanding” away as a close reason because it was being abused to mean “lack of research effort”. I fear the same thing will happen to “too broad” if people keep using it to close reasons “for lack of research effort.”

Comment: @GeorgeStocker _I am not discussing the close reason!_  Still that answer states questions like that will be closed! A lot of all this frustration will be avoided with _clear new guidelines_. I guarantee people will follow. But you can't just start moderating differently until they are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198392/discussion-between-george-stocker-and-modus-tollens).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No thanks, it's past midnight over here. I just had to vent my frustration for once. I know it's not your fault, I know change is difficult, but I am starting to get annoyed by the continuos, avoidable hassle. I finally want to know where we stand.

Answer (score 38):

This is a typical "Write my code for me" question.

One that lacks research, or any indication that the OP made any attempt at getting the desired outcome.

It can quite literally be answered with a dozen different approaches. It's textbook "too broad", and on top of that, also a duplicate.

Comment: I disagree. Does OP have to prove that they don't know how to solve the problem before allowing people to answer? I understand what you're saying and I do agree but in this case, I'm pretty sure OP knows how to solve it in a particular way, they're asking what the alternative could be.

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure OP knows how to solve it in a particular way"_ so why hasn't he shown any attempts?

Comment: Because that is not the point of this particular question. You're basically asking OP to post an example of what they don't want even though what OP doesn't want is pretty clear already.

Comment: Well, yes. It's never a bad idea to provide a function example of what you want to do, if you want to do it a different way.

Comment: Askers don't have to prove they know how to solve the problem, @customcommander; if they did, they could self-answer.  What askers *do* need to do is show that they're actually stuck somewhere when attempting to solve this.  Dumping a task on SO and saying, "Do this for me" isn't a question; it's a work request.

Comment: @fbueckert I mean no disrespect but the fact that your comment got so many upvotes proves my point about the vote count being a _take-it-with-a-pinch-of-salt_ indicator. You have actually misread what I said. What I said was: `Does OP have to prove that they **don't know** how to solve the problem before allowing people to answer?`. Even though what you're saying makes total sense, you're making a comment on something I just didn't even suggested.

Comment: @customcommander If I have misread your comment, I apologize, but I am unsure as to how I would have done so.  I pointed out that, no, the asker doesn't have to prove they don't know how.  I went on to expand with what askers *do* need to do, to refute the premise that the asker has met our standards.  They have not.

Comment: @fbueckert It's pub o'clock and I may be intellectually challenged right now but `Askers don't have to prove they know how to solve the problem` and `I pointed out that, no, the asker doesn't have to prove they don't know how.` don't mean the same thing to me ;) In any case I'm glad to see that the community does care. If I misread your previous statement, I do apologise too.

Comment: @customcommander there are members of the community that feel like people need to bend over backwards to ask a question. We don’t require that and in cases where the community closes questions for the wrong reasons we have a review queue and moderators hopefully rebuff the efforts to redefine what’s acceptable.